# How do I get dynamic content in an AngularJS Accordion body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I can see how to get static content in an accordion body, but can't figure out how to generate dynamic content.

Taking the example at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ the accordion is generated from ...

```
$scope.groups = [
    {
      title: "Dynamic Group Header - 1",
      content: "Dynamic Group Body - 1"
    },
    {
      title: "Dynamic Group Header - 2",
      content: "Dynamic Group Body - 2"
    }
  ];
```

What I want to achieve is generating an accordion from a two level structure thus ...

```
$scope.groups = [
    {
      title: "Dynamic Group Header - 1",
      items: {[item-title: "item 1", item-title: "item 2"]}
    },
    {
      title: "Dynamic Group Header - 2",
      items: {[item-title: "item 3", item-title: "item 4"]}
    }
  ];
```

Where each accordion body looks something like :-

```
<div ng-repeat="item in group[n].items"><li>{{item.item-title}}</li></div>
```

Such that the resulting HTML looks something like:-

```
Dynamic Group Header - 1
 . item 1
 . item 2
Dynamic Group Header - 2
 . item 3
 . item 4
```

Anything I put under content simply seems to get instantiated as innerHtml without any processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully got your use-case but assuming that you want to repeat over items inside accordion's body you could simply do it like so (markup):

```
  <accordion>
    <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in group.items">{{item['item-title']}}</li>
      </ul>
    </accordion-group>   
  </accordion>
```

When I was trying to use your JSON as an example I've noticed that it wan't well formated so it might be part of the difficulty you were facing. Here is the corrected JSON:

```
  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: "Dynamic Group Header - 1",
      items: [{"item-title": "item 1"}, {"item-title": "item 2"}]
    },
    {
      title: "Dynamic Group Header - 2",
      items: [{"item-title": "item 3"}, {"item-title": "item 4"}]
    }
  ];
```

and the working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/pjaekUXzvMQn9mOOArIH?p=preview

Comment: This works :-). 

I think I had overcomplicated the problem by going off in a wrong direction. I was trying to load the HTML into the content: field rather than have the simple HTML within the accordion-group. Many thanks.

Comment: How can i do the same in KO JS